# how to change the color of the rule (vertical line) in twocolumn document?

Tags: color, two-column, rules, multicol

I'd like to make the rule between the 2 columns very thin. I found that no matter how small of width I made it, the line was not thin enough for my liking (unless I make it zero, then it will disappear)

So I thought may be if I change its color to say gray or light gray, that will make it appear very thin.

I can change the width of the rule, but not its color:

[image]

Do I have to include `multicol` package for this? but when I tried

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.00001pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{0.5,0.5,0.5}}%
\begin{document}   
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

I see no change in the color. no matter what value I used. I must not be setting the columnseprulecolor correctly.

Also tried

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{red}}
\begin{document}   

\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

and few other things. So I give up.

How to change the color of the rule in twocolumn document?

**update**

Thanks to everyone for the answers. now it looks much better, now the line appears much thinner.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.01pt}
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, `\color{0.5,0.5,0.5}` should probably read `\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}` or `\color[gray]{0.5}`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Package `multicol`

`\columnseprule` only works inside environment `multicols`:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### LaTeX without package `multicol`

The rule can also be colorized without package `multicol`. Then `\@outputdlbcol` needs to be patched:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\newcommand{\latexcolumnseprulecolor}{\color{red}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@outputdblcol{% find
  \normalcolor\vrule
}{% and replace by
  \latexcolumnseprulecolor\vrule
}{% success
}{% failure
  \@latex@warning{Patching \string\@outputdblcol\space failed}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```