# Removing column line separators from a poster

Tags: multicol, multicolumn, posters

I want to prepare a 1 page poster involving columns using

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{multicols}{3}

\columnbreak

\end{multicols}
```

But I do not want the column separator line. How can I remove the lines?

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your requirements?

If you feel the answer is as per your requirements please upvote the answer by clicking on the red triangle at the left and the tick mark below it

The documentation for controlling the options of `multicol` are given at--http://mirror.iopb.res.in/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf

Also see--[how to change the color of the rule (vertical line) in twocolumn document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119110/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-rule-vertical-line-in-twocolumn-document)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I fix it by making the column separator color ''white'' so that it is invisible.

Comment: If you feel the answer is as per your requirements please upvote the answer by clicking on the red triangle at the left and the tick mark below it

Comment: Hm,  in the question title OP talking about poster. You use `article` ...  To help her/him we need more information (well question is year  and half old). which document class is used. BTW, by default there is no visible separation rule. It appear, if you define their thickness bigger than zero.